# How to remove dead threads from container

Tags: java, multithreading

I store threads in a container. With time, some of these threads will be running, and some of these will be dead. What i want to achieve is: automatically (or periodically) remove the dead (stopped) threads from the container.
What is the best way to do this?

**Edit:** I store my threads in a simple linked-list:

```
LinkedList<ServerThread> threadPool = new LinkedList<ServerThread>();
```

This container have to be dynamic, because with time, i have to add (and obviously delete) threads.

EDIT2: This is how i currently manage threads. As you can see, i wait for incoming connections, i don't know when it will arrive, but when it does, i have to handle it in a new thread.

```
while (!interrupted()) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                if (portNumber == Server.SMTP_PORT_NUMBER) {
                    threadPool.add(new SMTPThread(clientSocket, db));
                    threadPool.getLast().setName("SMTP Thread " + ++threadCounter);
                } else {
                    threadPool.add(new POP3Thread(clientSocket, db));
                    threadPool.getLast().setName("POP3 Thread " + ++threadCounter);
                }

                threadPool.get(threadPool.size() - 1).start();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us your container?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using one of the `ExecutorService` thread-pool classes?

Comment: No, there is no reason. I'm new to multithreading, i try this class.

Comment: what constitutes a "dead" thread?  one that is hung or one that has finished running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not maintaining your own list of threads unless there are specific reasons to do so.  I'd recommend using the excellent `ExcecutorService` classes that have been available since Java 5.  Something like the following:

```
// create a thread pool with 10 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// or you can create an open-ended thread pool
// ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (Job job : jobsToDo) {
    threadPool.submit(new MyJobProcessor(job));
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
...
public class MyJobProcessor implements Runnable {
    private Job job;
    public MyJobProcessor(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }
    public void run() {
        // process the job
    }
}
```

The thread-pool will take care of maintaining the running threads in the pool.  The threads will be re-used on the next job and will be shutdown when there are no more jobs in the pool and it has been shutdown.  You won't need to reap any dead threads yourself.

---

**Edit**:

In terms of the code you posted, to remove finished threads from your pool you should just run through them like:

```
 Iterator<ServerThread> iterator = threadPool.iterator();
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     ServerThread thread = iterator.next();
     if (!thread.isAlive()) {
        // remove it from the linked list
        iterator.remove();
     }
 }
```

I'd do this *after* each time you add a new thread to the pool.  Also, remember that `LinkedList` is not efficient to do a `get(#)` method call.  I'd recommend you tweak your code to do:

```
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ServerThread serverThread;
            if (portNumber == Server.SMTP_PORT_NUMBER) {
                serverThread = new SMTPThread(clientSocket, db);
                serverThread.setName("SMTP Thread " + ++threadCounter);
            } else {
                serverThread = new POP3Thread(clientSocket, db);
                serverThread.setName("POP3 Thread " + ++threadCounter);
            }
            serverThread.start();
            threadPool.put(serverThread);
```

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear: i cannot use a fixed sized pool. I'm implementing a server, and waiting for incoming connections. For every incoming connection, i have to start a new thread. Also, i have to know the list of the threads: when the server gets shutdown command, i have to stop all these threads.
So basically i dont know how many threads will run, and i dont know how many will run concurrently.

Comment: You can use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` to make the pool unbounded @Wonder.

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor (one of the java.util.concurrent ExecutorService implementers) supports flexibly-sized thread pools. To get the list of threads, you could specify a custom ThreadFactory for either this approach or Gray's above.

Comment: I edited my question, provided more code. I tried the ExecutorService, but it seems to be not working here.

Comment: I've updated my code with some reap code @Wonder.  I would still recommend using `ExecutorService` if you can.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also think about maintaining the container after each addition. Also, thanks for your tweak. I tried the ExecutorService, but it seems to be not an option here. :(

Comment: Notice that OP is already using `list.getLast()` (efficient) twice and then suddenly "forgets" about it in the third case. He could just use the same call the third time. Plus, if he's already got custom Thread subclasses, he should have implemented the thread name INSIDE those classes, the constructor only accepting `threadCounter`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah, i just don't know why used the get() function instead of getLast() at the third time. Also thanks for the tip with the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Timer` to schedule a periodic `TimerTask` that will run through the list and remove the dead threads. This is a sketch:

```
static final List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();
static final Timer timer = new Timer(true);
public static void main(String[] args) {
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {public void run() {
    for (Iterator<Thread> it = threads.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      if (!it.next().isAlive()) it.remove();
  }}, 0, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Right now i stick to Gray's solution, but i'll keep this method in mind, too, for other future tasks.

Comment: If you implement this solution, you'll have to watch out for synchronization, though. That's the advantage of Gray's proposal -- no race on the thread list. The advantage of this one is that it doesn't depend on the frequency of incoming requests to do its housekeeping.